# Java EE 6 Grizzly Comet Engine Single User Notify

Tags: java, comet, enterprise, grizzly

I am working on a project which requires server-sided pushes similiar to websockets. Of course websockets arent supported in EE6, so I integrated the grizzly Comet Long Polling mechanism. 
The project is running on a glassfish 3.1.2.

My problem is, I require that the event that is thrown into the comet event handling is delivered ONLY to one specific user. Currently, every logged in user receives the event.

All tutorials, examples and use cases of the comet engine were either chat systems or streaming applications. Is there a way to send one event to only one specific user at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is websockets a requirement for your project?

Because there are already mechanisms in the EE-specification for Publisher-Subscriber-mechanisms, JMS the most prominent.